# How to get two json value from one ngrepeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to get two JSON array value in one ngrepeat.

```js
var app = angular.module('testApp',[]);
app.controller('testCtrl',function($scope){
   $scope.res ={};
   $scope.res.fsus = [
  {
    "statusMessageType": {
      "MasterConsignment": {
        "ReportedStatus": {
          "ReasonCode": "var"
        },
       "time": {
          "timeA": "2017-10-01T10:15:00.000Z"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "statusMessageType": {
      "MasterConsignment": {
        "ReportedStatus": {
          "ReasonCode": "car"
        },
       "time": {
          "timeA": "2017-10-01T10:15:00.000Z"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "statusMessageType": {
      "MasterConsignment": {
        "ReportedStatus": {
          "ReasonCode": "car"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "statusMessageType": {
      "MasterConsignment": {
        "ReportedStatus": {
          "ReasonCode": "car"
        },
        "time": {
          "timeA": "2017-10-01T10:15:00.000Z"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "statusMessageType": {
      "MasterConsignment": {
        "ReportedStatus": {
          "ReasonCode": "ban"
        },
       "time": {
          "timeA": "2017-10-01T10:15:00.000Z"
        }
      }
    }
  }
];

$scope.opts = [];
angular.forEach($scope.res.fsus,function(key,value){
  if(($scope.opts.indexOf(key.statusMessageType.MasterConsignment.ReportedStatus.ReasonCode , 0)) <= -1){    $scope.opts.push(key.statusMessageType.MasterConsignment.ReportedStatus.ReasonCode);
  };
if(($scope.opts.indexOf(key.statusMessageType.MasterConsignment.time.timeA , 0)) <= -1){    $scope.opts.push(key.statusMessageType.MasterConsignment.time.timeA);
  };
});
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
<li ng-repeat="test in opts">
  <span class="step">    {{test}}
  </span> 
  <span class="title">    {{???}}
  </span>
</li>
</body>
```

And I also want to change format of this time YYYY-DD-MM@ HH:MM.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: hey did the answer help?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object with status and time using angular.forEach and use that in ng-repeat

```
$scope.opts = [];
angular.forEach($scope.res.fsus,function(key,value){
if((($scope.opts.indexOf(key.statusMessageType.MasterConsignment.ReportedStatus.ReasonCode , 0)) <= -1) && (key.statusMessageType.MasterConsignment.time)){    $scope.opts.push({'status':key.statusMessageType.MasterConsignment.ReportedStatus.ReasonCode,'time':key.statusMessageType.MasterConsignment.time.time});
  };
});
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('testApp',[]);
app.controller('testCtrl',function($scope){
   $scope.res ={};
   $scope.res.fsus = [
  {
    "statusMessageType": {
      "MasterConsignment": {
        "ReportedStatus": {
          "ReasonCode": "var"
        },
       "time": {
          "time": "2017-10-01T10:15:00.000Z"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "statusMessageType": {
      "MasterConsignment": {
        "ReportedStatus": {
          "ReasonCode": "car"
        },
       "time": {
          "time": "2017-10-01T10:15:00.000Z"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "statusMessageType": {
      "MasterConsignment": {
        "ReportedStatus": {
          "ReasonCode": "car"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "statusMessageType": {
      "MasterConsignment": {
        "ReportedStatus": {
          "ReasonCode": "car"
        },
        "time": {
          "time": "2017-10-01T10:15:00.000Z"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "statusMessageType": {
      "MasterConsignment": {
        "ReportedStatus": {
          "ReasonCode": "ban"
        },
       "time": {
          "time": "2017-10-01T10:15:00.000Z"
        }
      }
    }
  }
];

$scope.opts = [];
angular.forEach($scope.res.fsus,function(key,value){
if((($scope.opts.indexOf(key.statusMessageType.MasterConsignment.ReportedStatus.ReasonCode , 0)) <= -1) && (key.statusMessageType.MasterConsignment.time)){    $scope.opts.push({'status':key.statusMessageType.MasterConsignment.ReportedStatus.ReasonCode,'time':key.statusMessageType.MasterConsignment.time.time});
  };
});
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
<li ng-repeat="test in opts">
  <span class="step">    {{test.status}}
  </span> 
  <span class="title">    {{test.time  | date:'MM/dd/yyyy @ h:mma'}}
  </span>
</li>
</body>
```

Comment: It is working but. It is giving me. duplicate value also. But previous code remove the duplicate value.

Comment: you just need to add a check

Comment: @Sajeestharan. thank for the comment. But every thing is same as previous. It should be work.

Answer (score 0):

This may help for You:

```
var jsonArray='your json array here';
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <body ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <li ng-repeat="test in jsonArray">
      <span class="step">    {{test.statusMessageType.MasterConsignment.ReportedStatus.ReasonCode}}
      </span> 
      <span class="title">    {{test.statusMessageType.MasterConsignment.time.timeA  | date:'MM/dd/yyyy @ h:mma'}}
      </span>
    </li>
    </body>
```